# How to achieve a basic setup of LineageOS with root and Google Assistant?

Tags: lineageos, google-assistant

It appears there are 4 things needed to get what I would consider a basic LineageOS install working so apps can run correctly with root.

1. [LineageOS](https://download.lineageos.org/)
2. [SU addon](https://download.lineageos.org/extras)
3. [Google Apps/Google Play Store](https://wiki.lineageos.org/gapps.html)
4. Google Voice Assistant

Could someone outline how to set up the last one "Google Voice Assistant"?  I also noticed there is no complete guide that I could find on StackExchange for setting up the above on LineageOS.  So I guess something like a guide would probably could be helpful as a canonical question.

Comment: As for Google Assistant... Try [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/android-7-0-google-assistant-t3535257) along with the latest Google App & Play Services.

Comment: Edited to remove mentions of downloads, as those are undoubtly off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is actually pretty easy if you phone is already unlocked.

1. Boot into recovery mode
2. Wipe the phone.  I advise going under advanced and checking everything unless you have files you need.
   [image]
3. [image]
4. I wipe everything including internal storage but you don't have to [image]
5. Install the zips starting with LineageOS, SU addon, Google Apps/Google Play Store & Google Voice Assistant.  You should not reboot your device until all are installed.
6. Reboot you device out of recovery mode and go through the set up menus.